# Does Guidewire support term change without rewrite?

Tags: guidewire

Out of the box, does Guidewire support term change without a policy rewrite?
Is there anyway I can test this on my local?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think so.  It's not possible to term change without rewrite because there might be chance term change might effect debatable or policy limitations and there is the high chance of change in premium.

Answer (score 2):

No. Guidewire does not support policy term change without rewrite OOTB. You have to cancel the policy and rewrite in order to change.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a bit old and I'm sure you've come to whatever answer you needed, but just in case someone else lands here in the future...

From an insurance point of view, there are a couple different versions of "changing the term". If the policy was originally entered/issued with the wrong term by accident, yes you likely need to just flat cancel and re-write it. There are a few legitimate situations where the "term" could change where nothing about the policy was ever invalid and *shouldn't* require a re-write/re-issue. One example is extending the term, common in construction projects. You wouldn't want to write a whole new policy for a couple week extension of a project that ran long. Another situation is more correctly termed "Extended Reporting Period" for certain types of professional liability policies that operate as "claims made". I've seen ERPs done as either a separate, but attached policy, or as a very special type of endorsement that gives a wider effective/expiration date as it relates to claims made policies. The last scenario I've run into as a consultant and as an insured is the need to "move" the effective/expiration based on a home purchase for a home owners policy when the closing date gets moved. In that circumstance we only ever processed those on bound, but not yet issued policies.

As for native Guidewire, I'm not able to answer that one as the last implementation project I worked on had started a few months before I was brought on board and that functionality was already there.

Side note, any time you are in a situation of altering term/effective periods of a policy, it is important to verify if there are any open/closed/pending claims impacted. We had one situation where the policy term simply had been entered wrong, but issued correctly from the MGA. The carrier denied a claim due to it being outside of the term a day or two before the policy was fixed. It was a week or two later when everyone realized what happened and the claim was also fixed after the insured's lawyer contacted the carrier for incorrectly denying the claim. All was eventually resolved though.